# Crashlytics initialization crash after upgrading Gradle version to 7.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

We recently upgraded our gradle build version to 7.0.3

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
```

App is crashing in release variant. When I tried removing minification, it does not crash. Here is the crash log for the same.

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics was not started due to an exception during initialization
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.b6.e cannot be cast to android.content.Context
    at com.zm.f4.get(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.c6.a.get(DoubleCheck.java:5)
    at com.a6.p.get(TransportRuntime_Factory.java:3)
    at com.a6.p.get(TransportRuntime_Factory.java:1)
    at com.c6.a.get(DoubleCheck.java:5)
    at com.a6.n.a(TransportRuntime.java:3)
    at com.rb.q0.c(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:8)
    at com.mb.b.a(Unknown Source:133)
    at com.mb.j.get(Unknown Source:3)
    at com.mb.p.get(Lazy.java:5)
    at com.mb.l.f(ComponentRuntime.java:5)
    at com.mb.l.g(ComponentRuntime.java:5)
    at com.gb.c.d(FirebaseApp.java:19)
    at com.gb.c.e(FirebaseApp.java:24)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:9)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:287)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

Extra information: I had to upgrade my JDK to 11 for successful build in my Jenkins CI/CD after upgrading gradle build version.

Also we have this mentioned in module gradle build file.

```
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: I confirmed by downgrading gradle build tools version as well, crash is not happening in that case.